# How to use multiple items in group by

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have data like:

```
[
    {"createdAt": 2022-02-10T00:00:00.000Z,name:'stack',value:'3'}
    {"createdAt": 2022-02-10T00:00:00.000Z,name:'google',value:'30'}
    {"createdAt": 2022-03-10T00:00:00.000Z,name:'stack',value:'33'}
    {"createdAt": 2022-04-10T00:00:00.000Z,name:'google',value:'32'}
    {"createdAt": 2022-03-10T00:00:00.000Z,name:'google',value:'31'}
    {"createdAt": 2022-02-10T00:00:00.000Z,name:'stack',value:'13'}
    {"createdAt": 2022-04-10T00:00:00.000Z,name:'stack',value:'23'}
    {"createdAt": 2022-02-10T00:00:00.000Z,name:'google',value:'33'}
    {"createdAt": 2022-04-10T00:00:00.000Z,name:'google',value:'43'}
    {"createdAt": 2022-03-10T00:00:00.000Z,name:'stack',value:'32'}
    {"createdAt": 2022-02-10T00:00:00.000Z,name:'stack',value:'35'}
    {"createdAt": 2022-04-10T00:00:00.000Z,name:'google',value:'38'}
]
```

Query

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$group:{_id:{$dayOfYear:"$createdAt",name:"$name"},"total":{$sum:"$value"}}}
])
```

Expected results:

```
[
    {name:google,date:2022-02-10:,value:63}
    {name:google,date:2022-03-10:,value:31}
    {name:google,date:2022-04-10:,value:113}
    {name:google,date:2022-02-10:,value:51}
    {name:google,date:2022-03-10:,value:65}
    {name:google,date:2022-04-10:,value:23}
]
```

I am trying to group by multiple items and getting the following error:

> An object representing an expression must have exactly one field: { $dayOfYear: "$createdAt", name: "$name" }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `$set` - Create `date` field with date-only string (via [`$dateToString`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/)).
2. `$group` - Group by `date` and `name`. For summing `value` as `total`, you need cast to integer via `$int` first.
3. `$project` - Decorate output document.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      date: {
        "$dateToString": {
          "date": "$createdAt",
          "format": "%Y-%m-%d"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        date: "$date",
        name: "$name"
      },
      "total": {
        $sum: {
          $toInt: "$value"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      date: "$_id.date",
      name: "$_id.name",
      total: "$total"
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jr8TbtBF7bt)